# Combining Results from 2 Queries. 1 of Which is a Joined Query

Tags: cognos

I have 2 list's that display data and provide totals.

One is a joined query, the other is a single query

I have tried to join the joined query and the single query but i can't get it to work.

Im trying to calculate a return rate. first list produces a total return amount for each salesman. The second produces total sales for each salesman.

In the 3rd list im trying to add and divide the totals to get my return rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using master details report. 
A great simple example can be found in the following video tutorial here: 
[Cognos 10 Training - Master Detail Report](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFWscNj7sgU) 
The basic steps are:

1. Create your master list and drag items into the list.
2. Drag additional list as a new column of the master list. So it should look like this: 
   [image]
3. Drag items to this list.
4. Now, make sure both queries contains the data item you want to join on. This data item does not have to appear in the list/s, but it must be part of both queries.
5. Select any item in the detail list and from the menu pick Data->Master Detail Relationships...
   [image]
6. Press the new link button and create the relationship between the 2 queries.

That's itm run the report and see the results.
A deeper documentation can be found on Cognos official documentation is here: 
[Create a Master Detail Relationship](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r2m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/t_cr_rptstd_modrep_create_master_detail_relationship_rel.html?path=3_5_10_6_7#cr_rptstd_modrep_create_master_detail_relationship_rel)